# nodejs - how to change creation time of file

Tags: node.js, file, last-modified

fsStat class instance returns mtime, atime and ctime date objects, but there seems to be API only for changing mtime and atime (last modification and access i guess). How can i change creation time to create exact copy of file as it'd be also created the same time as original one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible at present with Node itself, but you can use https://github.com/baileyherbert/utimes (a native add-on for Node) to change the creation time (aka `btime`) of a file on Windows and Mac.

Comment: It's Linux file server but w.e it works and it's actually better than what I used to use bc allows `undefined` to keep field unchanged.

Comment: On Linux, setting the `btime` is a no-op, but `mtime` and `atime` will be set on Linux if they are provided.

Comment: Huh? Why? I have btrfs RAID array and I want to backup and be able to restore low level file metadata. That includes btime. node stat on btrfs filesystem returns `atime`, `mtime`, `ctime` and `birthtime` (though `birthtime` and `ctime` are the same). I want to change them. And yeah I'm aware in UNIX ctime is not actually file creation time but last inode update but whetever. As long as I won't use hardlinks it's creation time

Comment: Oh... it seems linux actually explicitly forbids such operation and it requires changing system clock to old date, then creating hardlink to file and removing it, then setting system clock back to proper date... It's... pretty inconvenient...

Comment: As far as I understand Linux does not support the concept of `birthtime`. There is no Linux API to get or set a `birthtime` that I know of. Linux filesystems usually don't even have a field to store the `birthtime` of a file (even if Linux had the API to change it). Node introduces a dummy `birthtime` on `fs.stats` instances on Linux, which tracks `ctime` (which is meaningless). Windows and Mac are the systems which support `birthtime`.

Comment: well ext4 and btrfs do support it but it's not exactly birthtime of file because like I said it's date of last inode change so it changes when for example hardlink to file is created. However as long as there's no inode changes it'll remain date of file creation. And I checked node support for it and yes, ctime returned by `fs.statSync` is correct and it does change after hardlink creation.

Comment: `@ronomon/utimes` is not longer maintained and doesn't work on Catalina and latest Node.js

Check `utimes` instead -> https://github.com/baileyherbert/utimes

Answer (score 2):

**tl;tr:** That's not possible atm (Node.js <= v6).

Even though, [fs.stat()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) returns the [*birthtime*](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stat_time_values) of files:

> `birthtime` "Birth Time" - Time of file creation. Set once when the file is created. On filesystems where birthtime is not available, this field may instead hold either the `ctime` or `1970-01-01T00:00Z` (ie, unix epoch timestamp `0`)…
>
> **Prior to Node v0.12, the `ctime` held the `birthtime` on Windows systems.** Note that as of v0.12, `ctime` is not "creation time", and on Unix systems, it never was.

Updating is not possible. From https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8252:

> [fs.utimes](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_utimes_path_atime_mtime_callback) uses utime(2) (http://linux.die.net/man/2/utime), which doesn't allow you to change the ctime.

(Same holds for `birthtime`)

Comment: ctime is not creation time

Comment: @PA. thanks for mentioning, I've clarified my answer – at least on Windows, `ctime` has been used as creation time at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

The `fs.utimes` and `fs.utimesSync` methods are built into Node.js core. See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_utimes_path_atime_mtime_callback

Note:

> The value should be a Unix timestamp in seconds. For example, Date.now() returns milliseconds, so it should be divided by 1000 before passing it in.

To convert a JS Date object to seconds:

```
new Date().getTime()/1000|0
```

Comment: At least up to node v10.0, `fs.utimes` only updates `atime` and `mtime`, and not the field the OP wanted, which is `birthtime`.